# Getting the pixel co-ordinates of a Google map marker

Tags: coordinates, google-maps, pixel, latitude-longitude, marker

Is it possible to determine the pixel co-ordinates of a given marker, taking into account current zoom level and visible area of the map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current (v3):

```
map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(marker.position);
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Projection

Old (v2):

The method [fromLatLngToContainerPixel](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html) following should give you what you're after, assuming `markerPoint` is your marker, and `zoomLevel` your current zoom:

```
map.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(markerPoint.getLatLng(), zoomLevel);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's just the method I needed! (Actually it would be: 'map.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(markerPoint.getLatLng(), zoomLevel);' as the first parameter should be a GLatLng object.)

Comment: Updated to reflect markerPoint comment, and added direct link to documentation.

Comment: V3 does not support this method.